# how to temp store string path and make it as array to use in another action result?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

this is my code in controller

```
public ActionResult UploadFiles(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    string TempPath = Server.MapPath("~/TempImages/");
    foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
    {
         string filePath = Path.Combine(TempPath, file.FileName);
         Tempdata["paths"] =filePath;
    }
}
```

how in insert every time the path and get it as array / arraylist ?

update:
this is what really goes on for every image readed this action is running

```
 public ActionResult UploadFiles(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
 {
      if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/TempImages/")) || files !=null)
      {
           string TempPath = Server.MapPath("~/TempImages/");
           List<string> paths = new List< String> ();

           foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
           {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(TempPath, file.FileName);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, ReadData(file.InputStream));
                file.SaveAs(filePath);
                paths.Add(filePath);
                TempData["paths"] = paths;
            }

        }
        return view();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just do

```
public ActionResult UploadFiles(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    List<string> paths = new List<string>();
    foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
    {
        string filePath = Path.Combine(TempPath, file.FileName);
        paths.Add (filePath);

    }
    Tempdata["paths"] = paths;
}
```